# How do I repeat a choice in an Else/if format on Python?

Tags: python, loops, repeat, text-based

I am making a text-based game in Python, which I haven't touched in a while, for a class project. I want the game to use a name feature, and want the player to choose their `name`, so I put in a line of code that is supposed to allow them to repeat the line of code for entering their name. I am trying to use a loop for that, of course, but I don't know how to format it for an if/else statement.
Here's the code I have:

```
def naming():
  print("A long, long time ago, there was a person who was born very ordinary, but would live to become very extraordinary.")
  time.sleep(3)
  name=input("Who are you? Give me your name.")
  choice=input("You said your name was ", name,", correct?")
  if choice in Yes:
    prologue():
  else:
```

I want to put the whole thing in a loop so that it repeats, (Which is why I haven't defined the "else" at the end) but I want the loop to break if the player says "yes" when prompted. Thanks for reading this far!

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    name=input("Who are you? Give me your name.")
    choice = input(f'You said your name was {name}, correct?')
    if 'yes' in choice.casefold():
        break
```

Credits to devdev_dev

Comment: you can select an answer as correct and then its featured at the top for other people to reference it, so you don't have to write another comment with the final answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
while True:
    name=input("Who are you? Give me your name.")
    choice = input(f'You said your name was {name}, correct?')
    if 'yes' in choice.casefold():
        break
```

Comment: the choice is not a variable though, will that still work?

Comment: The answer is missing `name=input("Who are you? Give me your name.")` after `while True`

Comment: `input` just takes 1 argument and its a string, so you interpolate the variable into the string

Comment: Will it allow the player to re-enter if they say no?

Comment: yes the block of code in the loop will repeat until the user puts yes - its an infinite loop that only ends when you get your desired output - while loops really useful for this scenario

Comment: Thank you very much. I am still entering it and double checking, I'll have the results updated shortly

Comment: Never mind, it doesn't work.
It worked unless you say no. Then it uses 0, the default value, in place of the name variable and doesn't let you re-enter your name

Comment: I ended up using 'return' on the else statement and it works now. Thank you!